# Default drag-and-drop image upload captions to the filename

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images, uploader

After dropping an image into the "Drag and drop or click here" window, SE uploads it, but the image caption in the generated Markdown will still be the default "enter image description here"

[image]

GitHub does this better by defaulting the image to the filename. When users save screenshots, they may give them descriptive filenames, and it would save a bunch of typing if that filename was imported as the image description.

[image: GitHub defaults the image description to the uploaded filename]